# I'm seeing "rpcbind" errors on 13.04_x64 Startup

Tags: boot, 13.04

From my `boot.log`, I see this:

```
rpcbind: Cannot open '/run/rpcbind/rpcbind.xdr' file for reading, errno 2 (No such file or directory)
rpcbind: Cannot open '/run/rpcbind/portmap.xdr' file for reading, errno 2 (No such file or directory)
```

I'm running Raring 13.04 both x86 and x64 (two machines). Both machines show these same two lines in `boot.log` and I'm wondering how to fix it.

One post I've seen suggests opening `/etc/init.d/rpcbind` and adding

```
if [ ! -f $STATEDIR/rpcbind.xdr ]
then
    touch $STATEDIR/rpcbind.xdr
fi
if [ ! -f $STATEDIR/portmap.xdr ]
then
    touch $STATEDIR/portmap.xdr
fi
```

But `/etc/init.d/rpcbind` is empty on both my machines, so I'm not about to start mucking about, especially since this doesn't seem to be affecting anything else as far as I can tell. It's just a little annoying to see these errors fly by on boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating the two files listed (as root, of course). They are empty, but it stops the complaint when booting. The x64 is an NFS/http/tftp/BOOTP server, and does not seem to be affected either way. There was no problem with functionality before, and none after. The only change is the absence of the error from the boot log.